Free/loose mode content translation with paragraphs
The content_translation module available since Drupal 8 allows me to translate content pages (entities/nodes) in a very strict mode: Each paragraph on the source language page has a translated equivalent in the target language.
I'd like to have a more free form approach to the translation; a page in the translated language may have completely different content than the source language.
Example:

Source page contains Headline, Image, Text
Translated page contains only Headline and Image, but the Text paragraph is removed. Another Image is added.

Basically I want to be able to have content/paragraphs on page that are only available in a specific language.
How can I achieve this?

What you are looking for is called "asynchronous translation" or "asymetric translation" and this is not supported by Paragraphs. There are patches which try to implement this, but I advise against using them. They simply are not stable and quite error-prone in the long run. My personal opinion: The idea of asymetric translation is wrong by concept, if two pages have different content in different languages, than this is not a translation, this is a different page. Create a new node instead.

If you just want to hide some paragraphs on the translated version, stay with symetric translation, and make the paragraph entity and the paragraph publish field translatable instead.

Does this answer your question? Cannot change layout of translated paragraph nodes

Hi CW. e.g. providing health information for various demographic groups. Certain groups being more likely to face certain health issues seems to call for unique information per language. But bear in mind translation is not equal to unique landing pages per language by concept. Information should not be lost in translation. Asynchronous translation is a pseudo term to describe unique content in different languages. This is challenging to implement, not just in Drupal. I would argue strongly with my team why one demo group would not have access to info provided to another demo group.

Maybe you can get the result with https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs_asymmetric_translation_widgets ?
